# moving to httpClient from http throwing error in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create new wrapper for restservice, i am trying to move angular 4 to 5 and upgrading the same service. i get error like below. If i change `Observable<Response>` to `Observable<HttpResponse>` also i get error:

> Argument of type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
>   Property 'headers' is private in type 'HttpHeaders' but not in type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?:

below is code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';    
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';    
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class httpService {
    private requestHeaders: HttpHeaders;

    constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
        this.requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        this.requestHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.requestHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    }

    post(url: string, requestData?: any): Observable<Response> {
        return this._http.post(url, requestData, this.requestHeaders);
    }
}
```

---

Above is fixed by using `{headers: this.requestHeaders}`

but while line  `return this._http.post(url, requestData, this.requestHeaders);` throws error like

```
Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>'.
Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'Response'.
Property 'body' is missing in type 'ArrayBuffer'.
```

Comment: There's no `Observable<Response>` as a return type of `httpClient.get`. You can either use `Observable<any>` or `Observable<HttpResponse<any>>` .

Comment: It is an http.post method

Comment: They have the same return types (even their overloads).

Comment: Observable<HttpResponse<any>> did not work just any works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

headers is only one parameter of the options, so you should be passing in

```
{headers: this.requestHeaders}
```

This will also fix the `Property 'headers' is private...` error you are seeing.

---

Also, [HttpHeaders](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#description) is immutable. So every mutation operator returns a new instance. This means to properly set the headers you will need to do

```
this.requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
    .append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .append('Accept', 'application/json');
```

or

```
this.requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
this.requestHeaders = this.requestHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.requestHeaders = this.requestHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');
```

---

**Updated:**

So the post observable is returning of type `Observable<ArrayBuffer>` but your method is declared to return type `Observable<Response>` causing the type mismatch. The `HttpClient` expects you to pass in the return type to the method `this.http.post<YourResponseType>(...)` (or it will assume the return type). So your method should be updated to

```
post<T>(url: string, requestData?: any): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.post<T>(url, requestData, {headers: this.requestHeaders});
}
```

where `T` is the response type. Now the http method is expecting to return type `Observable<T>` and your `post` method is returning type `Observable<T>`. The types match. You would use your method like so

```
this.post<MyResponse>(myUrl, myRequestData).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Can you look at new error i am getting. Updated the question.

Comment: @Hacker you still want the `T` syntax. You would only return `HttpResponse` if you passed in `{observe: 'response'}` to the options. If you were to pass in that parameter then you could pass in `<HttpResponse<MyResponse>>` to your post method `this.post<HttpResponse<MyResponse>>.subscribe(...);`

Comment: Just wondering how the method post(url: string, requestData?: any): Observable<Response> {
        return this._http.post(url, requestData, this.requestHeaders); be updated the clear the issue. 
    }

Comment: @Hacker I'm not sure what you are asking. The HttpClient methods (get, post, put, etc..) do not return type `Response` like the old Http methods. Instead it assumes that json is being returned. That is why you pass in your desired response type `this.post<YourResponseType>()`. The HttpClient will parse the response and say it is of type `YourResponse`.

Comment: Got your point return value of get, post is JSON, i was confused there.  The calling function i will update to this.post<MyResponseType>(). But my post method is global function called from anywhere. How will i pass MyResponseType to Observable<MyResponseType>. Sorry i am quite a newbie to this.

Comment: @Hacker that is where `T` comes into play. It is called a generic. Your global function should return `Observable<T>`, so when you pass in `this.post<MyResponseType>()` `T = MyResponseType`

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `append()` is:

```
append(name: string, value: string|string[]): HttpHeaders { 
   return this.clone({name, value, op: 'a'}); 
 }
```

It returns a clone of hte headers object. You need to store/assign the returned result to your variable `this.reqequestHeaders` otherwise it would not be saved.

Alternatively, the constructor os HttpHeaders is:

```
constructor(headers?: string|{[name: string]: string | string[]})
```

A cleaner way to do is:

```
const headerJson = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept' : 'application/json'
}

this.header = new HttpHeaders(headerJson);
```

Comment: The header private variable should be of any type?

Comment: `header: HttpHeaders`  and also set return type for your post method: `post():Observable<any> {...}`

Comment: So Observable<any> is only option i can set over there for post().

Comment: @Hacker by using `any` you lose the ability to strictly type your response